# AWS hosted Opsworks Chef Automate - How to properly change server name

Tags: chef, opsworks

I'm in the process of writing my IaaC and am instantiating an AWS Chef Automate instance. I'm a newb when it comes to Chef server administration and Chef Automate has a billion moving parts. All attempts at properly changing the server name to now have failed.

After instantiating our Chef Automate instance, I want to change the default server name used to something under our control. Yes, this requires an update to the certificates for the server, which causes me to ask the question of whether I'm pointing the right nginx process to the right places.

- It appears that the instance uses chef templates for a private chef instance (on the instance?)
- knife is not installed on the instance, so I'm not 100% sure the best way to alter or even look at the node's attributes, but I'm assuming this is the best way to make the changes I want to make. (right?)
- I've tried manually altering `nginx.conf` properties, which doesn't work at all.
- I cannot find documentation for what I seek anywhere on the googles.
- I've tried engaging opsworks, but that's not yielding anything of substance.

Anyone out there a Chef Automate guru who can point me in the right direction? I need the following:

1. Change the `servername` that the webserver/chef answers to
2. Change the certs to which nginx et al points.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...at least for my use case. NOTE that in practice, I usually comment out old stuff rather than just edit it in place. I recommend the same for the following in case you need to revert anything:

1. do your certificate magic and put your certs in place.
2. edit `/etc/delivery/delivery.rb`

   - set `delivery_fqdn` to the new name you want your server to run as.
   - set `delivery["ssl_certificates"]` to point to the proper certs you just set up.
   - check everything else, but I doubt you want to change anything else.
3. make sure your DNS is set up properly.
4. run: `delivery-ctl reconfigure`